# Number of Email Clicks per Subscriber

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-studio

I'm trying to report on the number of clicks per subscriber for either a single email send or multiple. I'be been looking but can't seem to find this? Is it possible to obtain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating a query on system data views in marketing Cloud.

Write a query by making an inner join with `_sent` data view and `_click` data view on the relevant field. Store these results in standard data extension and export it manually or via automation.

[**Here is an example**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/using_the_query_activity/query_find_subscribers_with_no_opens_or_clicks/) of how to find subscribers with no opens and no clicks.

Modify the query as per your needs.

Data View: [**_Sent**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/using_the_query_activity/data_views/data_view_sent/)

Data View: [**_Click**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/using_the_query_activity/data_views/data_view_click/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Automation Studio to query the click view as suggested above.

But To be simple, you can track the clicks by going to Email--> Tracking.
If it is via Triggered send, then click the respective mail and click export.
It will have all the details.